# Incoming form JSON not being decoded

Tags: php, ajax, json

Using an ajax call I send a json data packet to a php back-end, however the `json_decode` fails on it for an unclear reason. The php code in question is here:

```
$request = file_get_contents('php://input');
Logger::getInstance()->debug("Request: ".$request);
// The logger shows the following line after a sample submission: 
// Request: prospectname=OMEGAK&teaserimg=kb.png&submit=Submit
$data = json_decode($request, true);
Logger::getInstance()->debug("Data: ".var_export($data,true));
// The logger shows the following line after a sample submission:
// Data: NULL
```

The packaging of the json comes from a variety of similar posts, but I'm using the following script (which is simply trying to send up a json-encoded key-value map of the form submission):

```
(function (){
  $.fn.serializeObject = function()
  {
      var o = {};
      var a = this.serializeArray();
      $.each(a, function() {
          if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
              if (!o[this.name].push) {
                  o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
              }
              o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
          } else {
              o[this.name] = this.value || '';
          }
      });
      return o;
  };

  $(function() {
      $('form').submit(function() {
          var $blah = $('form').serializeObject();
          // The $blah object reads like so at this point:
          // {"prospectname":"OMEGAKB","teaserimg":"kb.png"}
          var promise = $.ajax({ 
            url: 'myform/save',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $blah,
            type: 'POST'
          });

          promise.done(function (result) {
            alert("Success: "+result);
          });

          promise.fail(function (result) {
            alert("Failure: "+result);
          });

          return;
      });
  });

})();
```

Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong, and why the php seems to convert or be getting bad incoming data?

Comment: I believe that it's not json, but my understanding is that it *should* be json. Why is it not?

Comment: Why are you trying to post in JSON anyways?

Comment: You need to echo or print the PHP result to respond. This can be done with `echo json_encode($whateverYourSendingBack);`.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone; it appears that a lot of this isn't working due to jQuery version conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Is prospectname=OMEGAK&teaserimg=kb.png&submit=Submit the json you are referring to? If so, that's not json. That's a url string. http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

`dataType: 'json'` doesn't convert your data to json. It tells the server that your attempting to send json.

`JSON` stands for `*javascript* object notation`. So when you using the jquery.serializeObject(), you actually get an object in return.

Straight from php.net:

```
<?php
$query = "my=apples&are=green+and+red";

foreach (explode('&', $query) as $chunk) {
    $param = explode("=", $chunk);

    if ($param) {
        printf("Value for parameter \"%s\" is \"%s\"<br/>\n", urldecode($param[0]), urldecode($param[1]));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the receiving php end needs json so converting it on that end isn't actually an option.

Comment: Are you not in control of the receiving end? If not, then we need to see exactly how the PHP server that you are not in control of is parsing the data. I have never seen a PHP server require json.

Comment: I disagree that you need access to that scope. The reason for requiring json is that the api being hit digests json, not a url encoding. This send needs to work against multiple agents.

Comment: I did not say I needed access. I said we need to see how the PHP server is parsing the data. My guess is it's not doing it the same as the code you posted above.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually sending JSON. 
You're creating a JavaScript object and passing it to $.ajax which converts it to a query string and posts it(It does not convert it to JSON). You can use `JSON.stringify` to convert an object to JSON.

```
data: JSON.stringify($blah),
```

Comment: Doing this produces the exact same result. I was also told that `ajax` will do that for you, but I may have been misled in that. Regardless, it goes up as a query string with or without that?

Comment: Well you forgot to stop the form from submitting.

Comment: Care to elaborate? That sounds very much like what I'm seeing.

Comment: You need to return false from the submit handler, not just return.

Answer (score 1):

not 100% sure without seeing your entire code, but i believe since you're doing "return" in the end instead of "return false" or "e.preventDefault()", the standard submit button behavior is triggered, and the form is actually posted without ajax.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `url` in your `ajax` method is not a php page. Change it to the `path.php` to test this theory. Handle the `$data` on your PHP page as you would with an Associative Array, then `echo` or `print` the results within `json_encode()` that you want to go back to handle with jQuery, like:

```
echo json_encode($results);
```